# SQL Union Not Displaying all results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I am trying to display both the credit column as well as the debit column but it is putting both amounts into one column and displaying only the credit heading.

For each statement description there is a credit and a debit amount.
I need it to populate so that i can see Statement_description = credit
and below statement_description debit

```
`SELECT PR.[Statement_Description]
      --,PR.[Debit_Acc_Num]
      ,PR.[Credit_Acc_Num]
      ,PR.Actual_Txn_Amount as Credit_Amount
      ,Actual_Txn_Date
      ,PBY = '949'
      ,VatCode = 'E'

         FROM [Financial].[dbo].[Payment_Request] PR
             inner join SharedData.dbo.StaffData SD
                on PR.Prepared_By = SD.StaffNo 
  where  
   ID_Payment_Status = '1'
  --and Prepared_By_Date = (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) + '14:00' as date )
  and (Debit_Acc_Num  like '1%' or Debit_Acc_Num like'2%') 
  and (Credit_Acc_Num like '1%' or Credit_Acc_Num like'2%') 
  and Debit_Acc_Num <> 0
  --and Credit_Acc_Num <> 0

union  

  SELECT PR.[Statement_Description]
      ,PR.[Debit_Acc_Num]
      --,PR.[Credit_Acc_Num]
      ,PR.Actual_Txn_Amount as Debit_Amount 
      ,Actual_Txn_Date
      ,PBY = '949'
      ,VatCode = 'E'

     FROM [Financial].[dbo].[Payment_Request] PR
             inner join SharedData.dbo.StaffData SD
                on PR.Prepared_By = SD.StaffNo 
  where  
   ID_Payment_Status = '1'
  and (Debit_Acc_Num like '1%' or Debit_Acc_Num like'2%') 
  and (Credit_Acc_Num like '1%' or Credit_Acc_Num like'2%') 
  --and Debit_Acc_Num <> 0
  and Credit_Acc_Num <> 0
    order by Statement_Description
`
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management studio

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Union all still only gives me the credit column and not the debit column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,take '0' as DebitAmount in first union and Credit as your originalAmount then in next union do it same for Credit.

```
  SELECT PR.[Statement_Description]
  --,PR.[Debit_Acc_Num]
  ,PR.[Credit_Acc_Num]
  ,0 as DebitAmount
  ,PR.Actual_Txn_Amount as Credit_Amount
  ,Actual_Txn_Date
  ,PBY = '949'
  ,VatCode = 'E'

     FROM [Financial].[dbo].[Payment_Request] PR
         inner join SharedData.dbo.StaffData SD
            on PR.Prepared_By = SD.StaffNo 
where  
ID_Payment_Status = '1'
--and Prepared_By_Date = (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) + '14:00' as date )
and (Debit_Acc_Num  like '1%' or Debit_Acc_Num like'2%') 
and (Credit_Acc_Num like '1%' or Credit_Acc_Num like'2%') 
and Debit_Acc_Num <> 0
--and Credit_Acc_Num <> 0

union  

SELECT PR.[Statement_Description]
  ,PR.[Debit_Acc_Num]
  --,PR.[Credit_Acc_Num]
  ,PR.Actual_Txn_Amount as Debit_Amount 
  ,0 as CreditAmount
  ,Actual_Txn_Date
  ,PBY = '949'
  ,VatCode = 'E'

 FROM [Financial].[dbo].[Payment_Request] PR
         inner join SharedData.dbo.StaffData SD
            on PR.Prepared_By = SD.StaffNo 
 where  
 ID_Payment_Status = '1'
and (Debit_Acc_Num like '1%' or Debit_Acc_Num like'2%') 
  and (Credit_Acc_Num like '1%' or Credit_Acc_Num like'2%') 
--and Debit_Acc_Num <> 0
and Credit_Acc_Num <> 0
order by Statement_Description
```

Comment: thanks this worked perfect, but how can i do a balance at the end to show that the credit is equal to debit as i need to export it into an excel doc, as this is going to be an automated thing when done. to show that the balance is equal to zero

Comment: you can wrap the whole query in a single tab and then calculate SUM for credit and debit as you have two separate columns now.Then Calculate difference as u want.